# R sentiment using WebCorpus() and YahooFinanceSource()

Tags: r, batch-file, web, yahoo-finance, sentiment-analysis

Happy Holidays! I have a question when using WebCorpus(YahooFinanceSource()) and like to ask for help. I am debugging a large application but come down to a small code piece. The codes can run perfectly fine as a single file in the RStudio environment or in line-by-line interactive mode in the RStudio console, but fails in running in a batch file for command shell using `Rscript` or `R CMD BATCH`. The error only happens for the yahoo finance source. It is good for other sources like google finance and reuters. Here are the codes, say the filename is sentitest.R that runs fine in the RStudio V0.98. My test platform is `CentOS release 6.4 (Final)`.

```
library(XML)
library(tm)
library(tm.plugin.webmining)
library(tm.plugin.sentiment)
stock <- "IBM"
wbcorpus <- WebCorpus(YahooFinanceSource(stock))
```

Then I created a batch file sentibatch that contains only one line as follows and changed it to be executable.

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore sentitest.R
```

I ran the sentibatch command in the shell:

```
$ sentibatch
```

But it came with the following errors from the .Rout file (I did not include the preface of it).

```
> stock <- "IBM"
>
> wbcorpus <- WebCorpus(YahooFinanceSource(stock))
StartTag: invalid element name
StartTag: invalid element name
StartTag: invalid element name
StartTag: invalid element name
Opening and ending tag mismatch: e2 line 2 and description
Opening and ending tag mismatch: e2 line 2 and item
Opening and ending tag mismatch: description line 2 and channel
Opening and ending tag mismatch: item line 2 and rss
Premature end of data in tag channel line 2
Premature end of data in tag rss line 2
Error: 1: StartTag: invalid element name
2: StartTag: invalid element name
3: StartTag: invalid element name
4: StartTag: invalid element name
5: Opening and ending tag mismatch: e2 line 2 and description
6: Opening and ending tag mismatch: e2 line 2 and item
7: Opening and ending tag mismatch: description line 2 and channel
8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: item line 2 and rss
9: Premature end of data in tag channel line 2
10: Premature end of data in tag rss line 2
Execution halted
```

Here is the session info. The OS is `CentOS release 6.4 (Final)`. All packages were installed.

```
> sessionInfo() 
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Rscript sentitest.R` works fine for me

Comment: Can you try to create sentibatch, change it to be execuatble, and then run it in the shell? Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't understand my comment. R CMD BATCH is a an old manner to launch R scripts as batch. On windows,  I am using `Rscript` to launch R scripts, and it works fine for me. I don't have an ubuntu machine to test on linux and let you know!! FYI the equivalent of Rscript on ubuntu is : `sudo apt-get install littler` ! good luck!

Comment: You do not need a second, executable file:
you can simply add `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` as the first line of your R file,
and make sure it is executable (`Rscript` is available on all platforms).
As for the error messages you get, they are probably unrelated to the way you launch your code;
they indicate that the web page did not have the expected format
and could not be parsed -- but I cannot reproduce the problem: 
your code works fine for me.

Comment: To @agstudy, I tested `Rscript sentitest.R` in CentOS release 6.4 (Final), but still generated the same error. Note that it works fine in RStudio, and also that it works fine if the code is `wbcorpus <- WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource(stock))`, i.e., the source is changed.

Comment: To @Vincent, thanks for your reply. I added `#!/usr/bin/Rscript` to be the first line of `sentitest.R` and change it `excutable`. Then both `sentitest.R` and `Rscript sentitest.R` produced the same error. Again, if the finance source changes to be google, it works fine. The same running environment as before. It must be very tricky.

Comment: So it works in RStudio, but NOT with R BATCH or Rscript? What if you run R interactively from the prompt and type the functions in there? My guess is that you have some kind of network problem from the command line, maybe RStudio has configured itself to use a proxy that the command line doesn't. But that doesn't explain why other sources work. Maybe Yahoo doesn't like your headers? Just to be clear, all your tests - the working RStudio and the failing BATCH are from the same machine? Please edit the question now to make it all clear.

Comment: Yes, the R BATCH or Rscript does not work for yahoo source. It works fine interactively from the prompt. The network problem or proxy guess does not explain why other sources work. Not sure how headers can change. THe RStudio and Batch/Rscript tested are on the same machine.